# Inheritance and utility methods and variables

Tags: java, oop

I'm used to using inheritance only where the child class is a more specific version of the supper class. Therefore, I wonder if it is correct to inherit a class from an ancestor to store only a variable in the parent class (that will be used by all inherited classes).

Example:

```
public abstract class EmployeeDetail{
    
    private final Employee executor;

    public EmployeeDetail(final Employee executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    protected Employee getExecutor(){
        return this.executor;
    }

    public abstract boolean edit(final Employee id);

}

public class EmployeeDetailLevel1 extends EmployeeDetail {

  public EmployeeDetailLevel1(final Employee executor) {
    super(executor);
  }

  public boolean edit(final Employee id){

    // some implementation that works with parent executor variable
    return false;

  }

}
```

**Question:**

1. Is this code correct from OOP perspective? In this case probably yes, because parent class `EmployeeDetail` specifies one abstract method, but if there is no abstract / normal methods?
2. What if I need some utility methods that use all subclasses? Should I to move it into another static utility class or is it ok to place in `EmployeeDetail`?

Comment: why wouldn't it be correct? It still makes it more specific, since every EmployeeDetailLevel1 might be an EmployeeDetail, not every EmployeeDetail is an EmployeeDetailLevel1

Comment: In this case, I am more interested in question of storing the variable and possibility the existence of "utility" methods that use inherited classes - if is it ok to place it in parent class or to exclude into external utility class.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of reasons why I wouldn't do this:

- The superclass is a *bad* object. It doesn't abstract anything, i.e. it doesn't contain any knowledge that is exclusive to it.
- It doesn't encapsulate its state. I.e. its state isn't private.
- The two are very tightly coupled, subclass may break if superclass changes, Liskov, etc. Subclassing is *expensive*.
- More importantly, it indicates that an abstraction is missing.

Every time you have a "utility", or want to "share code" this way it means that you are missing an abstraction. There needs to be something that does the thing you want to share, and does it exclusively. It may define a different interface for downstream things at the same time which no longer need this logic anymore.

Comment: What do you thing is better approach how to implement this type of "shared" functionality without using a super class? Any design pattern?

Comment: What I described above could be summarized as *composition over inheritance* with an *adapter pattern*. You basically pack the "common logic" into the *Adapter*, and offer a simpler interface to all *Adaptees*, who will not need this logic anymore.